# Have a python while loop append to a file, without writing over previous content

Tags: python, loops, output

I have managed to create a quite complex script which loops over a number of dates to do day-by-day searches on twitter.com, downloading a set number of tweets per day, and writing the data to a text file.

The full code is here: [my code](http://pastebin.com/9QsYsuUB)

What am I doing wrong? Why is the output file overwritten by every iteration of the loop, instead of appending?

Comment: Could you please highlight the specific loop you are referring to?

Comment: It is the writing operation on lines 258-260 that I want to append to the file, rather than overwriting. It is about how the `write_f` is dealt with.

Comment: This doesn't address your problem, but traditionally, class definitions do not go inside while loops. One typically leaves them at the global scope. It's also quite unusual to have an `if __name__ == "__main__":` conditional that far down in your code. Typically, it's supposed to contain all of your executable code.

Comment: Could you add the loop snippet to your question and the definitions of all variables involved? This would help with answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file in read-write mode (rb+), instead of opening with the append mode (a).